# Can anyone translate the language of Mrs Cameron's diary?

Tags: colloquialisms

There is a spoof column in *The Guardian* every Saturday called *Mrs Cameron's diary*. It purports to record the thoughts of the Prime Minister's wife, Samantha. However it is written in a language which to a person of my age is unintelligible - I am supposing that it is largely a texting form.

I am recording below a few sentences from last Saturday. Could anyone possibly translate them into standard English, please?

> ***Sarah's like hey bff -
>   where r the bongos?***
>
> *Well I said to Mummy at a guess Sarah Govey has now sent 50 texts that go hey Sam I do hope our boys won't spoil our friendship, u R my
>   bff for ever, Sam I promise I am not really bffs with Marina, just
>   pretending until June 23rd, btw you look super gorge on the FROW do
>   you get a discount at Burberry, Marina's clothes are well tragic!!!!
>   If you see the stuff in the Mail pls tell Dave soz Dacre made me, so
>   blame him, btw Sam if you have last week's Grazia can I have ur free
>   gift plus Michael needs his bongos back, Mr Lebedev luvs bongos PS his
>   beard is real he says he luvs my work!!! luv u lots Sarah.*

I am of course aware that *Sarah Govey* is the wife of Michael Gove, a Conservative politician, and colleague of Cameron, who has joined the campaign to leave the EU - and that their two wives are very good friends. I also realise that *Marina* is the wife of Boris Johnson, who has also joined the *leave camp*.

In particular, can anyone translate *bff*; *FROW*;*Grazia*; *ur*; *bongos*?

Comment: Personally, I love detailed questions on text speak, I was puzzled more by FROW and 'soz' than anything else. As for 'bongos' I still don't get it. David Cameron has borrowed Sarah's husband's bongos. Why? Is it implying that the PM is faking friendship with someone? Is it used as a type of stress reliever, a bit like punching at a pillow?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know. I don't understand it at all. The Goves and the Camerons are having to keep their distance at the moment as Gove has installed himself in the anti-EU camp. And if the Referendum produces a *leave the EU* result, most believe Cameron will be forced to resign as PM.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So *FROW* means "**f**ront **row**", customarily at a fashion show, i.e. right up at the catwalk. It's a status symbol in the airy world of fashion. Then *soz* is simpler: *sorry*. Text speak has a habit of precious *z*-substitutions (though I find this one harder to analyze than the simple plural markers I'm used to; maybe *sorry* -> *sorree!* -> *sorrees!* -> *sorreez* -> *sorz* -> *soz*?). In re: bongos, that's unrelated to text speech, that's the journalist making a timely pun on [Lebdev's friendship with President Bongo of Gabon](https://www.instagram.com/p/yHUY1UjvW9/).

Comment: @DanBron Dacre refers of course to Paul Dacre, the editor of the Daily Mail, a man whose life is dedicated to perpetuating the simplicities and misconceptions of the mostly ignorant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>***My gut tells me one-off translations are "too localized" to answer on EL&U, and normally in that case I would provide a translation in the comments at vote to close.***</sub>

<sub>***However, given the length of the passage, I will not have space to translate the whole thing in a comment, so I'll add an answer here, which can be deleted along with the question if/when it is closed (usually, I either answer or VtC, but once I've done one, I refrain from doing the other, lest I make a hypocrite of myself).***</sub>

<sub>***Either way you'll know what Sarah is going on about.***</sub>

> Well I said to Mummy at a guess

This I suppose you already understand.

> Sarah Govey has now sent 50 texts

*Texts*, here, are *text messages*. The messages you send from your phone to someone else's. The preferred medium of the current generation.

> that go

*That say* (the *quotative go*, maybe?).

> Hey Sam I do hope our boys won't spoil our friendship,

*I hope our husbands won't come between us.*

> u R my bff for ever,

*You are my best-friend-forever (bff), forever.*

> Sam I promise I am not really bffs with Marina,

[Despite whatever rumors you may have heard,] *I am not bffs (best-friends-forever) with Marina.*

> just pretending until June 23rd,

*I'm just pretending to Marina to be her good friend*, [for some purpose,] *until the 23rd of June*.

> btw you look super gorge

*By the way (btw), you look super gorgeous.*

> on the FROW

*On the front row* [of seats closest to the catwalk at the fashion show you attended].

> do you get a discount at Burberry,

*Do you get discount at Burberry* [you're always wearing such pretty things by them]*?*

> Marina's clothes are well tragic!!!!

*Marina* [does not dress well;] *her clothes, unlike yours, are so bad as to constitute a tragedy.*

[She suffers from either bad taste or penury. I do not like Marina, I like you. Please do not be upset at the rumors that we are spending time together.]

> If you see the stuff in the Mail

Presumably the capitalization implies the *Daily Mail*, a tabloid if I understand Britain's culture right, which would publish scandals about celebrities, and other gossip.

> pls tell Dave soz Dacre made me, so blame him,

*Please tell Dave that I am sorry (soz),* [regarding that scandal about me/us in the Daily Mail] *and that Dacre made me* [do whatever scandalous thing they're reporting on], *so blame Dacre* [do not blame me].

> btw Sam if you have last week's Grazia

*By the way (btw) Sam, if you have last week's [issue of] Grazia magazine*

I googled it. *Grazia* is a UK fashion magazine. Ms. Cameron seems very interested in fashion, as befits a socialite.

> can I have ur free gift

*May I please have the gift that came with that issue?*

Presumably the item is related to fashion, maybe a perfume tester. Something on that order.

> plus Michael needs his bongos back,

Unless *bongos* has some slang gloss (either Millenial or British or both) I'm unfamiliar with, I take this as written.

> Mr Lebedev luvs bongos

[The reason Michael needs his bongos back is] *Mr. Lebedev loves bongos.*

> PS his beard is real he says he luvs my work!!!

*Postscript*: *his beard is real, and he says he loves my work.*

[Since she speaks of Michael familiarly, presumably she's referring to Mr.Lebedev, here.]

> *luv u lots Sarah.*

*I remain your most faithful and obedient servant.*

Comment: Yeah, without knowing the larger context it's not implausible that "bongos" simply refers to the drum set used in Latin music.

Comment: @HotLicks I checked Urban Dictionary for *bongos*, and then did a broader (but still cursory) Google search, and I didn't come up with anything that seemed applicable.

Comment: Yeah, same here.  (The beard is consistent with "loving bongos".)

Comment: @HotLicks It's Thursday here, so I'm pretty sure *The beard is consistent with "loving bongos"* is going to be my quote of the week.

Comment: Well done! The significance of 23rd June, is that it's the Referendum date (on continued membership of the EU). Wish I knew what *bongos* were! Perhaps bongo drums, but I don't get the significance.

Comment: @WS2 I'm pretty convinced she just means bongo drums. Hot Licks came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @DanBron Just in case you are interested in [the whole thing](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/feb/26/mrs-camerons-diary-sarah-gove-bff--bongos-johnsons-kiss-lebedev-foot)

Comment: @WS2, Ok, I solved the Great Bongo Mystery. She is talking about actual bongos (the drums), but it's a play on / pun for the surname of the President of Gabon, who Mr. Lebdev is apparently on good terms with: https://twitter.com/mrevgenylebedev/status/557862564517138433 .

Comment: @DanBron Clearly I suffer from reading just the mainstream media.